# Se puede usar en netbeans 8.2 con Java 7 y JDK_10?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, netbeans-11, java-7

Buen día para todos.
¿ puedo trabajar en java 7 con netbeans 8.2 y JDK 10. ??
O para eso me tocaría usar apache netbeans 11.2 ??
Teniendo en cuenta que realizare un sistema talvez un poco pesado que usara gran parte de consultas en mysql y servidor tomcat 8.5.50

Comment: ¿Qué te hace pensar que se podría o que no se podría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oficialmente NO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53694286/6999690).

Netbeans 8.2 fue diseñado para Java 8 y por esa razón siempre busca en la carpeta que le indiques como raíz de tu JDK por un archivo "rt.jar" que son las librerías runtime, es decir las librerías que siempre se cargan para soporte a Java SE, sin ellas todo tu código te marcaría error y el autocompletamiento fallaría... a menos que.....

Uses una versión de desarrolllo, a varios desarrolladores metidos en la comunidad de netbeans por medio de nuestras listas muchas veces recibiamos alertas cuando existía una nueva versión Release Candidate o RC, para que hiciéramos un testing masivo de las nuevas funcionalidades.

Esto nos permitió a muchos practicar con la versión 9 RC probar jigsaw antes de que se lanzara al público en general, pues esta versión ya soportaba el recién salido [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9), con la desventaja de que cuando salieron los parches el proye cto creado con el IDE en esa versión quedó totlmente inútil, debido a que la integración final de netbeans con Jigsaw se hizo de manera distinta.

Sinceramente aunque [en mi blog](http://javapro.org/blog/java-9-hello-world/) he posteado como hacerlo no he probado von versiónes más recientes como [java-10](/questions/tagged/java-10).

Ahora, respecto al apache netbeans funciona excelente con Java 9, 10, 11, 12 y el preview de la 13, y no presenta problemas por el [source-level si necesitas compilar para versiones anteriores](https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/netbeans-quick-tip-1-setting-target-jdk), la única restricción es que tu **JDK la soporte**.

Si te preocupa la estabilidad te recomienod probar con [coolbeans](/questions/tagged/coolbeans), ahora llamado openbeans si no me equivoco.

También adicionalmente te recomiendo revisar siempre al iniciar un proyecto la página [stackshare](https://stackshare.io), en la que se comparten algunas combinaciones de herramientas y tecknologias para desarrollar proyectos.

## Acerca del soporte de versiones

El soporte gratuito para el Oracle Java 7 terminó en abril de 2015, así que si tuvieras problemas tendrías que confiar al soporte pagado que funciona hasta Julio de 2022.

[tag:Java 8], la siguiente versión terminó su soporte en enero de 2019 para uso comercial (soporte por parte de Oracle), el soporte de Oracle para uso personal termina en diciembre de este año 2020, hasta 2023 para el Adopt OpenJDK y en Junio 2023 para la versión de Amazon Corretto.

El JDK que pretendes usar de Java 10 tiene menos soporte que los dos previamente mencionados, pues [terminó en septiembre de 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history). **Por esa razón te recomiendo usar en su lugar un JDK 11** que es la versión con soporte extendido, cuyo soporte gratuito llega hasta 2022 para el AdoptOpenJDK y hasta Septiembre de 2026 par el soporte pagado con Oracle.

## ¿Qué retos implica?

Si no mal recuerdo, desde Java 12 ya no te permite compilar código de Java con un sourcelevel ya deprecado, así que lo más viejo que podrás manejar tu código es Java 7, y en próximas versiones solamente para Java 8 o superior, así que **yo procedería directamente a probar para compilar para Java 8 en vez de para Java 7 con el JDK 11+**.

Comment: Ok, pero tengo entendido que JDK11 ahora va ser de pago ya que oracle cobrara.
La verdad estoy mirando demasiados vídeos para hacer mi sistema, java 7 y 8 ya son algo viejos me encantaria empezar con versiones todo super actualizado pero no encontrado una buena guia para la instalacion y configuracion de mi entorno para desarrollar en java ya que uso demasiado los servlets para el patron mvc, entonces nose la verdad si exista un lugar donde pueda conseguir una buena guia para tener mi entorno funcionando bien.

Comment: Va a ser tna de pago como lo ha sido siempre, con la excepción de que ahora si despliegas alguna aplicaicón comercial compilada con el Oracle JDK tendrás que pagar. Pero en estos tiempos modernos, sinceramente muchos desarrolladores que contribuimos al open source usamos un Oracle JDK para compilar en nuestro local y mandamos nuestros binarios con el Open JDK u otra versión. En mi caso particular me gusta mucho usar Zulu porque no contiene JavaFX.

Comment: Ok y me recomiendas usar el jdk 13 ?? ya que iva intentar descargar el jdk 11 y me mando a la 13

Comment: Es bueno, pero es demasiado nuevo para el uso en código de empresas, yo me iría por el 11 o el 12, si tu proyecto es open source no habría ningún problema.

Comment: Oye muchas gracias, grandiosas respuestas